# pytest fixture that returns a class in which the results of using requests.request are saved in a json file

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a fixture for an ApiClient. With a pytest flag I want to have a condition in which if the `--record` flag is passed, the ApiClient returned in the fixture has the usage of `requests.request` modified such that it records the results of the requests in a .json file.
this is the code I've got, but it's not working

```
def record_requested_data(*args, **kwargs):
    response = requests.request(*args, **kwargs)
    # Save the response in a JSON file
    record_path = os.path.join("recorded_responses", f"{args[0].replace('/', '_')}.json")
    with open(record_path, 'w') as record_file:
        json.dump(response.json(), record_file)
    return response

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def api_client(record_mode: bool):
    if record_mode:
        api_client = get_api_client()

        with pytest.MonkeyPatch().context() as m:
            m.setattr(requests, 'request', record_requested_data)

        return mp_api_client
    else:
        return FakeAPIClient()
```

When I run the tests with the flag, it enters the `if record_mode` condition (so the flag is working) but if I put a debugger inside the `record_requested_data` function it never executes that part. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. You are applying the patch in a way that makes in a no-op
2. You are patching the wrong thing

### Bad patch logic

You are monkeypatching the `requests` module like this:

```
api_client = get_api_client()

with pytest.MonkeyPatch().context() as m:
    m.setattr(requests, 'request', record_requested_data)

return mp_api_client
```

You are using the `pytest.monkeypatch.context` mechanism, which means any patches you make are removed when the context exits. Your `return mp_api_client` statement is outside of the `with` block, which means at that point all the patches have been cleaned up.

Even if you were to move the `return` statement *inside* the `with` block, it would still be ineffective: the context would be cleaned up when the function exits.

To make this work, you need to use a [`yield` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended), like this:

```
def api_client():
  api_client = get_api_client()

  with pytest.MonkeyPatch().context() as m:
      m.setattr(requests, 'request', record_requested_data)
      yield mp_api_client
```

Using `yield` like this means that the context remains active while the fixture is in use in your test, and is only cleaned up when the test is complete.

#### Wrong target for the patch

You've patched `requests.request`, but if you examine the source of the `requests` module, the `request` function (and `get`, `post`, etc) are all defined in `requests.api`. Patching `requests.request` is effectively a no-op, unless you explicitly call `requests.request`. You're calling `requests.get`, which will run `requests.api.get`.

Here's a version of your test that works. I've simplified a few things and made up others since your question didn't provide a complete reproducer, but I think it should be sufficient to demonstrate the solution:

```
import pytest
import requests


class ApiClient:
    def get_data(self):
        res = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        return res.json()


def record_requested_data(*args, **kwargs):
    response = requests.request(*args, **kwargs)
    # Save the response in a JSON file
    with open("requestlog.txt", "w") as record_file:
        record_file.write(response.text)
    return response


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def api_client():
    api_client = ApiClient()

    with pytest.MonkeyPatch().context() as m:
        m.setattr(requests.api, "request", record_requested_data)
        yield api_client


def test_apiclient(api_client):
    api_client.get_data()
```

Note that here we are *explicitly* making use of the fact that `requests.request` holds a referenced to the *unpatched* function; if that were not the case, this would end up just recursively calling `record_requested_data`.